# Salesforce1: All record pages loading with errors

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am testing configuration of compact layouts in Salesforce1.  Before making any changes, I logged into the Salesforce1 app from an iPad Air.  Everything was working fine.  I created a new compact layout for accounts and assigned it to the users and now when I log back into the Salesforce1 app all record pages are loading with no formatting.  The text and buttons are all bunched up and overlapping.  I have cleared the cache on the app logged out and logged back in, but it will not render properly.  I have seen this before with other changes/customization that I have done to the Salesforce1 app. Any advice how to fix?

Comment: I used to uninstall and reinstall the app .I also encountered this error many times after creating compact layouts .

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Salesforce1 app (5.0.2) that was released on Dec 16th? What iOS version is your app running on? I just tried it on my iPad running iOS 7.0.4 and it worked okay for me after I cleared the cache from app settings.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Can it be closed?